RegEx for variable-length delimited string in Adobe Classification Rule Builder
I have a string of values with a pipe delimiter. We've recently added two more variables to the end of the string for capturing going forward, so the string will either have 6 or 8 values.
Two example strings with junk values:
unknown|yes|no|true|false|maybe
unknown|yes|no|true|false|maybe|optional|optional

The regex I've written so far is:
^(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)

It captures perfectly if all 8 values are there, but doesn't cover the 6-value string. I just can't quite figure out the "or" statements needed to account for this.

I guess you want ^(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)(?:\|(.*)\|(.*))?

Thanks for your reply - that didn't work. It still only matches to 6 groups, it just pushes the first groups into one (so it looks like unknown|yes|no in match 1). But this gets me closer, for sure.

What about ^([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)(?:\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*))?$

Oh wow that's so close - it works when there are 6 groups and 8 groups but not 7. Unfortunately, 7 is a possibility I need to account for. That said, thank you for your help on this - I'm way closer than I was.

Aliright. Then ^([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)(?:\|([^|]*))?(?:\|([^|]*))?$

THANK YOU. Oh my gosh - thank you so much!
